# sql weekly totals by weekday

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-date-functions

I need to show a weekly total in a calendar way using MS-SQL.
Out of a table like this one:

```
Id, auto-increment
WC, text (Departament)
Product, text
StDate, date (Stamp Date)
Completed (T/F)
```

I can easily create an SQL to sumarize like this:

```
SELECT T.WC, T.StDate, T.Product, Count(T.Id) AS [Daily-Total]
FROM Table T
WHERE (((T.Completed)=True))
GROUP BY T.WC, T.StDate, T.Product
HAVING (((T.StDate)>=Date()-7 And (T.StDate)<=Date()));
```

And shows something like this:

```
WC      StDate      Product Daily-Total
Finish  01/01/2017  Prod03  4
Finish  05/01/2017  Prod02  2
Finish  05/02/2017  Prod02  2
Robot   01/01/2017  Prod01  4
Robot   02/01/2017  Prod03  4
Robot   03/01/2017  Prod02  2
Robot   03/02/2017  Prod02  2
Tack    01/01/2017  Prod01  7
Tack    01/01/2017  Prod02  4
Tack    01/01/2017  Prod03  4
Tack    01/01/2017  Prod04  4
```

But my boss wants me to show it this way (numbers not real):

```
Week10 WC     Prod  Monday Tuesday Wensday Thrusday Friday Saturday
       Tack   Prod1      1       0       3        2      0        0
       Tack   Prod2      0       1       0        1      1        0
       Robot  Prod2      3       1       2 ...
       Finish Prod1      1       4       5 ...
       Finish Prod3      3       4...
```

I thing I would need some nested or sequential Selects but either way I can not find a good solution.

If someone has been through this I appreciate any advice.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lookup `PIVOT for SQL Server`

Answer (score 0):

use PIVOT table concept :

```
  CREATE TABLE #table ( WC VARCHAR(100),  StDate DATE , Product VARCHAR(100) 
                        , DailyTotal INT , _DayName VARCHAR(50))

  INSERT INTO #table ( WC ,  StDate , Product , DailyTotal)
  SELECT 'Finish','01/01/2017','Prod03',  4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Finish','05/01/2017','Prod02',2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Finish','05/02/2017','Prod02',2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Robot','01/01/2017','Prod01',4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Robot','02/01/2017','Prod03',4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Robot','03/01/2017','Prod02',2 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'Robot','03/02/2017','Prod02',2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Tack','01/01/2017','Prod01',7 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'Tack','01/01/2017','Prod02',4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Tack','01/01/2017','Prod03',4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Tack','01/01/2017','Prod04',4

  UPDATE #table SET _DayName = DATENAME(WEEKDAY,StDate)

  SELECT *
  FROM 
  ( 
     SELECT WC ,  StDate , Product , DailyTotal , _DayName
     FROM #table
  )A
  PIVOT
  (
    SUM(DailyTotal) FOR _DayName IN      
    (Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,saturday,sunday)
  ) AS  unpvt
```

Comment: @ Juan M. Chapa,Try above PIVOT query.Is it gives your result or not...?

Comment: **Absolutely did!** great idea, thank you very much.
I finally found out that the ERP I'm using has a _dashboard_ utility that helps me create the Pivot Table by drag & drop. It worked great, thanks a lot @Mansoor.